# How to disable Save As A Copy in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Adobe writes

> When you check the “As a Copy” box, the copy is saved, but the working document continues to be the original instead of the copy.

I don't want to use this feature. I'm accustomed to the just saved document being the working copy. Adobe turns this feature on against my wishes. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

This horrible Adobe feature has bitten me on a number of occasions.

Comment: If you working using layers and save it as jpeg, png or gif, that option is always mandatory because jpeg files cannot contain layers.

Comment: Has a solution been found for this? None of these responses answer the question. I've JUST ran into this for the first time ever and its infuriating because I've never had this issue before in my 10 years of working in PS. I've always been able to overwrite existing files with the same name, as a .jpg, regardless of layers/channels/modes etc.

Comment: You can not disable this feature. Its been like this since forever. Only time it allows yoi to write over without doing this is if you opened the jpeg in first place

Answer (score 3):

Flatten your artwork before saving and it will then save to a jpg format natively.

**Layer Panel Menu : Flatten Artwork**

Be aware, saving a JPG as a JPG will **degrade the image quality** with *each* and *every* save.

---

The "as a copy" checkbox is automatically ticked when you attempt to save the open document to a format which does not support some of the current image structure.

For example...

- An open document with layers will not save as a JPG natively
- A CMYK document will not save as a GIF natively
- An open document with transparency will not save as a JPG natively
- A 32bit document will not save as a PNG natively
- And more...

Photoshop "saves as a copy" in order to remove or discard image data which can not be saved to a particular format. Since it's a *copy*, the original structure of the document is left *in tact* in the open document window.

If you do not wish to see the "Save as a copy" checkbox ticked, you must ensure the open document adheres to the capabilities of the format you wish to save to.

---

It is a feature designed to *save you from yourself* and prevent you from saving to a format which causes you to *lose* image data unexpectedly.

Comment: I just flattened a psd document and saved as a jpeg. It saved the jpeg as a copy. This has happened to me before and I do more work on a jpeg, hitting command s periodically as is my habit.
Then I notice it's still a PSD but my layers are destroyed.

Comment: It's not *only* layers that will cause the "as a copy" to be on.. channels, paths, or *anything* not supported in the jpg format can cause the copy to be on.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained why you can't switch off the "As a copy" option, I'll offer you a workaround.

One simple method is to duplicate the document first by using *Image > Duplicate*. So when you then save it as a jpeg, you can just close the jpeg document window after it has finished saving, and the original layered file will still be open.

Don't forget to save your original document as a PSD if you want to work on it in future. Jpegs can't contain layers, and you can't recover the layers from a jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

There's one case where "As a copy" is checked while it's NOT a format issue and it's absolutely *infuriating*: when you use Save As on a file  that you simply want to save under a different name before editing. When you use Save As, by default it obviously selects a compatible format, but it'll STILL check "As a copy" simply because a file with the same name already exists. But it'll also RENAME the file automatically by adding "copy"! Which means it makes no goddamn sense. Whoever came up with this should be forced to work in Photoshop without a keyboard for the rest of their life.